# Angular.js: How to use ng-model outside its scope

Tags: angularjs

I have searched a lot for this and couldn't get an appropriate answer. I am sorry if i am asking this question again. I am new to Angular.js

my code:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="x in setno" ng-init="parentset=$index">SET {{ x.alpha }}</th>


        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="(parentset,ques) in selected">

               <td ng-repeat="x in setno">
                <select ng-model="ques" ng-options="y.name for y in topics"></select>{{ques.qid}}


            </td>
            <td>{{$parent.ques.qid}}hi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="x in setno">

                <button ng-click="addques($index,ques.qid)" ng-model="ques.quid">add{{$parent.ques.qid}}</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The **ques** ng-model is working fine just after the *select* tag **but inside *td* tag only**. How can i use it outside that particular tag. 
ie, here: 
`<td>{{$parent.ques.qid}}hi</td>` 
and  here: 
`<button ng-click="addques($index,ques.qid)" ng-model="ques.quid">add{{$parent.ques.qid}}</button>`?

I have tried **$parent** and without it, but its not working. 
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs accessing ng-model from outside the $scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289408/angularjs-accessing-ng-model-from-outside-the-scope)

Comment: You did not search before asking this question: https://www.google.com/search?q=Angular.js%3A+How+to+use+ng-model+outside+its+scope&rlz=1C1ASRM_enZA677ZA677&oq=Angular.js%3A+How+to+use+ng-model+outside+its+scope&aqs=chrome..69i57.239j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The **select** tag has his own scope so you have to extend an object in the parent scope if you want to use "ques" out of the **select** tag.

To do so, create an object (a $scope variable) in the parent :

```
$scope.test;
```

And extends it in the select (the child scope) :

```
ng.model = "test.ques";
```

Then you can access "ques" out of the select tag.

Comment: I made an object $scope.test in my main controller as you said and then in my **select** tag and **td**, **button** tags i used *test.ques.qid*. It is only working in the first tag and not in the other tags.

Comment: Yes, that's doesn't work with `ng-model="test.ques.quid"` because `test.ques` is not an object of the parent scope so you can't extend it.Try to create a $scope.test.ques in the parent scope !

Comment: Is it OK @jAYANTYADAV ?

Comment: i am still having trouble. Consider this code: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xw4Dus?p=catalogue), although I have  `$scope.id` in my controller. look only for `ng-model="id"`

Comment: Same issue : you create a **$scope.id** in the child (select tag), so it overrides the parent scope property **id**. If you want to share **id**, create an object in the parent and extend it with the property **id** so you can edit it in the child scope and access in the parent.